# IIS 7 - URL Redirect Regular Express

Tags: regex, iis

I have a public URL pointing to a download that no longer exists.  I want to redirect users who hit the URL to a new file.  The URL is formed as such

https://ourdomain.com/admin/desktop/Filename-2014-03-28a.exe

The part of the URL that changes is "-2014-03-28a" which can be any string between "Filename" and ".exe"

How do I write the regular expression that matches this pattern but DOES NOT match the new filename to prevent a redirect loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rewrite Rule as follows:

In Match URL section:

- **Requested URL**: Matches the Pattern
- **Using**: Wildcards
- **Ignore case**: checked
- **Pattern**: admin/desktop/Filename*.exe
- **Using**: Regular Expressions

In the Action section:

- **Redirect URL**: admin/desktop/NewFilename{R:1}.exe

Notes:

- The Back Reference {R:1} takes the string "-2014-03-28a" and transplant it in the new URL.  Therefore **admin/desktop/Filename-2014-03-28a.exe** becomes **admin/desktop/NewFilename-2014-03-28a.exe**
- This is tested using IIS 7.5